# Angular - Getting JSON data from HttpClient in a service not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular-promise, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get JSON data in Angular using a service and I'm getting data with HttpClient using the `get()` method.
The problem is I'm using Promise and the function is returning a promise with the value inside it.

I printed the value in the console and it's returning:

> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
> controls: (22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},}

[image]

Here is the service code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable,of, interval, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators  } from '@angular/forms'
import {STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  controls:any=[]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.controls=this.getControlsData()
  }

  public async getControlsData():Promise<any> {

    console.log(firstValueFrom( (this.http.get("../assets/json/controlsData.json"))))
    return await firstValueFrom( (this.http.get("../assets/json/controlsData.json")))
  }

  public addControl(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("../assets/json/controlsData.json");
  }



}
```

Component:

```js
ngOnInit() {

    this.data=this.DataService.getControlsData()

}
```

Comment: What is the `data` type in your component? Meanwhile, can you share the JSON response as code snippet in the question? You should change the `ngOnInit()` as async method Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Promise? and not a subscription to the response? is it a mandatory thing?

Comment: @YongShun data:any
And thanks i changed the ngOnInit as async method and it's working fine !!!

Comment: @FlorenciaCames 
I already used observable instead of promise but the data isn't loading at time, the ngOnInit was putting a blank array (because the data isn't loaded yet) to this.data  so i searched for a solution and found that i need to use promise and wait/async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make the `ngOnInit()` method asynchronous.

```
async ngOnInit() {
   this.data = await this.DataService.getControlsData();
}
```

Or assign the value during callback via `Promise.then()`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.DataService.getControlsData().then((response: any[]) => {
    this.data = response;
  });
}
```

Or would suggest not to use `Promise` but return an `observable`, so your component to **subscribe** the observable (depend on your use case if you able to select not to stick with `Promise`).

Comment: Promise.then() is returning undefined but the first one is working fine thanks.
I already used observable instead of promise but the data isn't loading at time, the ngOnInit was putting a blank array (because the data isn't loaded yet) to this.data